# Suspicious call to Collection.contains method in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am getting a warning that `watchStore.contains(s)` is a suspicious call to `java.util.Collection#contains`.  How can I fix it? I want to use `contains()` to find a particular object with the matching serial number.

```
public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber(long srch) {
    long s = srch;
    Watch watch = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < watchStore.size(); i++) {
        watch = watchStore.get(i);
            if(watchStore.contains(s)) {
                System.out.print("item found");
                return watch;
            }
    } 
    System.out.print("item not found");
    return null; // watch is not found.
}
```

Comment: can you add the stack trace of the error you are getting

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: What is `watchStore`?

Comment: What watchStore collection holds? Watch or long?

Comment: Where does the `watchStore` come from?

Comment: watchStore is an arraylist

Comment: watchStore holds Watch @uber bot

Comment: @Nabstar here you are looking long typed value - if(watchStore.contains(s)){

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that `Watch` is the class, `watchStore` is a `List<Watch>`, and that a field `serialNo` exists on `Watch`...

```
public Optional<Watch> findWatchBySerialNumber(long serial) {
    return watchStore.stream()
                     .filter(w -> w.getSerialNo() == serial)
                     .findFirst();
}
```

If you're not using Java 8, the code is close, but a bit more dangerous since you have the chance to return `null`.  If you can use Guava's `Optional`, that'd be a better choice here.

```
public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber(long serial) {
    for(Watch w : watchStore) {
        if(w.getSerialNo() == serial) {
            return w;
        }
     }
     return null;
}
```

---

Your `contains` isn't going to work since your list doesn't contain `Long`s, it contains `Watch`s.  This is also why the compiler sees it as dubious; `contains` accepts an `Object` but it will return `false` if what you're looking for doesn't have a comparable `equals` for what's in your list.

You have to iterate over the entirety of your collection to find it in this scenario, especially since you're looking for a specific property on those objects as opposed to a specific, easy-to-provide value.

Comment: Hi Makoto, what dors the code return in the Java 8 exemple if the object is not found? Also null I guess?

Comment: No, it returns an instance of `Optional`.  You have to invoke the optional to get either the value, or take some default action.  [Take a look!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: the code compiled but its not returning the object that contains that "serial number". because I try to print out the object but nothing printed. why ?

Comment: @Nabstar:  Are you sure that you've overridden the default `toString()` method for that object?

Comment: yes its overridden... but am not using it to print out the object that has the matching "serial number". am simply using the `System.out.print()` to print it when `findWatchBySerialNumber(long serial)` returns the object.

Comment: That makes use of your object's `toString` method.  Very briefly, what do you get back when you print the value out?

Comment: actually nothing its blank

Comment: Are you certain that an object with the I'd you supply exists?  Seems like it doesn't.

Comment: yh an object with the matching serial number exist inside the arraylist because I printed what is inside the list using a loop with `.get(i)` method and I found its exist...

Answer (score -1):

> please how can I fix that. I want to use the contain() to find a
>   particular object with the matching serial number.

In that case override Watch's equals() to use serialNumber field for comparison.

Then add constructor that accepts serialNumber.

```
public class Watch {
    private final long serialNumber;

    public Watch(long serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this ||
            (obj instanceof Watch && ((Watch)obj).serialNumber == serialNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)serialNumber;
    }
}
```

Replace `if(watchStore.contains(s)){` with `if(watchStore.contains(watchToFind)){` where `Watch watchToFind = new Watch(s);`

Comment: You're creating a new instance any time you want to search the collection.  While this doesn't have a lot of potential of becoming computationally expensive, it's counterintuitive.  What then happens if you need to find more than one field is that you now have to update your code in two places as opposed to one.

Answer (score -2):

you can use contains method from  org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils package.

Checks if the value is in the given array.

The method returns false if a null array is passed in.

Parameters:
    array the array to search through
    valueToFind the value to find
Returns:
    true if the array contains the object

long [] imageHashes=  {12l,13l,14l,15l};
 System.out.println(ArrayUtils.contains(imageHashes, 13l));

Comment: Nothing there is an array, they're all `ArrayList`s.

Comment: Please add details to your explanation next time Nitin. This does not really help OP

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils  checks if the value is in the given array.

This method returns false if a null array is passed in.

Parameters:
    array the array to search through
    valueToFind the value to find
Returns:
    true if the array contains the objec